# In 3.68 Why is the picker and translate gizmo has been swapped with transform gizmo

Tags: 3d-view, tools, gizmo

Why are gizmos mixed up in 3.68 mixed up? Select tool is using "Transform" gizmo which gets in way of selecing, Move gizmo doesn't appear after choosing, missing. 3D cursor is also showing up as transformafter clicking.. it's a
wkward to place. Rotate, Scale, and Transform gizmos are working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer, after double checking, I don't have an exact answer for swapped and missing gizmos.. Except that it involved an object that was "copied and edited from an object whose X/Y locations were locked." After unlocking the X/Y locations in the N panel for the "copied object", the gizmos were functioning normally again. So if translate gizmo is missing, or not working, object is probably locked.

Comment: 3.6.8 hasn't been released yet anyway so it's probably still undergoing some updates.

Comment: @JohnEason But this link https://www.blender.org/download/lts/3-6/ says, 3.6.8 LTS was released on January 16th.

Comment: Oops. Yes. Apologies you're right and I'm already using it. :^(  It's 3.6.9 that's on the [Blender Builds](https://builder.blender.org/download/daily/) daily builds page. It  looks as if I need some new glasses!